# Asp function returns string that's a mixture of newlines and \n

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I'm transitioning an asp application from dotnet framework to dotnet core, and in the process, some of my views have started returning weird returns with a mixture of newlines literals and \n.

My code:

```
public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string componentName)
{
    var styling = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"wwwroot/css/{componentName}.css");
    return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
}
```

My view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

  @await Html.InlineStyle("document-styles")

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
...
```

My stylesheet looks like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

In the past the page would return as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-family: "Nunito Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

But now it comes back as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

  <style>\nbody {\nfont-size: 18px;\ncolor: #FFFFFF;\nfont-family: "Nunito Sans",\nHelvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\nline-height: 1;\n}\n</style>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

The browser still renders this correctly, but the unit tests now fail because what's returned is invalid.  I'm guessing this is down to encoding as I had a similar kind of issue come up.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment (yet) so have to post as an answer. It does sound like an encoding issue and there could be a few things causing it. I had a similar issue some time back. Have you tried to replace the new line characters manually?

```
public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string componentName)
{
    var styling = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"wwwroot/css/{componentName}.css");
    styling = styling.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
    return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
}
```